# Unable to add SSL certificate using Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, ssl, retrofit

Unable to add SSL certificate using Retrofit 2 getting below error:

java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "abcd.com": No address associated with hostname

Below is the code:

```
     try {
cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
cert = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.abcd); 
ca = cf.generateCertificate(cert);
cert.close();

String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
.sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory())
.build();

} catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException | KeyManagementException e) {
Log.e("Certificate Exception",e.toString());
e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
Log.e("Certificate Exception",e.toString());
e.printStackTrace();
}
```